How to access K8s pods through external IP?
I deployed my django app in kubernetes, and then created a service of LoadBalancer type to expose it.
This is the deployment yaml file (I changed the actual image name to <my_image>):
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: django-deployment
  labels:
    app: django-app 
spec:
  replicas: 2 
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: django-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: django-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: django 
          image: <my_image>:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 512Mi
              cpu: "1"
            requests:
              memory: 256Mi
              cpu: "0.2"

and this is the service yaml file:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: django-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: django-app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000
  type: LoadBalancer

when I run the command "minikube tunnel", it gives my running pods an external ip, and I can access it in my local computer. But when I tried to access from my other PC, it failed. I've read that for this kind of thing, I should have created a service of type NodePort:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: django-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: django-app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000
      nodePort: 30001 
  type: NodePort

I ran the command "minikube ip", it returned an ip address and I tried to access my django app by the url "http://<ip_address>:30001/", but is not working. Not from the other PC, nor the local one. Why is this happening? How can I expose this pod to the internet?

What do you mean by exposing the pod to the internet. Do you mean from any network or your local network?

Like, is there a way I can access to the django rest API running in the pod from any network?

I just stumbled on this thing called Kubernetes Ingress, seems promising

@Moon Yes, an ingress is the way to go here. Be careful what you choose as your ingress controller.

This question is similar to: How to expose kubernetes service on prem using 443/80. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

NodePort binds with the host ip, so now there may be two scenarios:

if you are running minikube with container runtime socket on the base Linux machine then it will directly binds with the physical machine i.e. your laoptop/desktop.

If you are running minikube on Windows using WSL2 or running VMs on platforms like VirtualBox / VMWare/ KVMs, etc. then NodePort will binds with the VMs IP.


Hope this answer's your question.

Check Dockerfile rather than Kubernetes.
if the Entrypoint doesn't specify the host it's running on or you customized it to 127.0.0.1.
change it to 0.0.0.0 for now if it's not production and apply other for production run according to Django standards and recommendation
also check port that container exposes and ensure it matches the target port
